# how to assign the value of match expression to a 2-dim array's elements in scala?

Tags: scala

```
def longestPalindrome(s: String): String = {
    val f = Array.ofDim[Boolean](1001,1001);
    var len = s.length();
    for (i<-0 to len-1; j<-i to len-1) {
        f(i,j) = i match {
            case j => true ;
            case x if x==j-1 => if (s(i) == s(j)) true else false;
            case y if y<j-1 => if (s(i) == s(j)) f(i+1,j-1) else false;
        }
    }
}
```

It complains about this line `f(i,j) = i match {` :

> Line 5: error: too many arguments for method update: (i: Int, x: Array[Boolean])Unit

What does it means? I just assign the value of match expression to a 2-dim array, what error happens?

Comment: You've got a number of things going wrong here. I'll mention only three. 1st - Indexing a 2-D `Array` is done like this: `f(i)(j)` 2nd - Your method is supposed to return `String` but nowhere do you compose or access a `String` to return. 3rd - `case j` creates a new variable of the same name, thus hiding the other `j` and _always_ returning `true`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are experiencing is due to the fact that you are not using the right syntax to access a 2D array.

To put it into context, the syntax to access an arbitrary `n`th element in the array is

```
array(n)
```

and if you think about it, a 2D array is just an array of arrays, meaning that to access the inner array you could do something like

```
val inner = nested(n)
inner(m)
```

Or in short

```
nested(n)(m)
```

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that you are trying to access the elements of the array with f(i,j).

You should use f(i)(j)

```
scala> val f = Array.ofDim[Boolean](1001,1001);
    f: Array[Array[Boolean]] = Array(Array(false, false, false, false....
scala> f(1,1)
<console>:13: error: too many arguments for method apply: (i: Int)Array[Boolean] in class Array
     f(1,1)
       ^

scala> f(1)(1)
res1: Boolean = false
```